# ASP.Net Razor Pages - How do you return json from a razor page to javascript $.getJson?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, razor

I am very new to web development and I've been searching around for a while now and I can't seem to find a solution to this. I am using razor pages in asp.net core 2.0 and I want to fill a drop down box based on another drop down box's selection. I set up the below javascript to hit a procedure in my razor page when the value of the first drop down box changes. When I run the code though, I can't get it to work. I think it is due to my return value but I can't seem to get that to be a json value as it keeps throwing an error at me when I try to. The error is that "JSON is not valid in this context". Can anyone suggest to me how to return JSON from razor pages to a javascript call?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
    @section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Department').change(function () {
        var selectedDepartment = $("#Department").val();
        var cardSelect = $('#Card');
        cardSelect.empty();
        if (selectedDepartment != null && selectedDepartment != '') {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetCardsByDivisionAndStatus")', { divisionID: selectedDepartment }, function (cards) {
                if (cards != null && !jQuery.isEmptyObject(cards)) {
                    cardSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                        Card_ID: null,
                        Card_Number: ""

                    }))
                    $.each(cards, function (index, card) {
                        cardSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                            Card_ID: card.Card_ID,
                            Card_Number: card.Card_Number
                        }));

                    });

                };

            });                                
        }
    });
</script>
```

}

And here is my C# code (I tried used JsonResult but that's not working either):

```
           // If the user selects a division then make sure to get the cards for that division only
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetCardsByDivisionAndStatus(string divisionID)
    {
        int checkinStatus;
        int intdivisionID;

        if (divisionID != "0" && divisionID != null)
        {
            // Retrieve a status of checked in so that only cards with a checked in status can
            // be checked out.
            checkinStatus = linqQuery.GetCardStatusByStatusDesc("Checked In", _Context);

            intdivisionID = Convert.ToInt32(divisionID);

            // Retrieve list of cards that have the checkin status ID
            CardList = linqQuery.GetCardListByStatusIDandDeptID(checkinStatus, intdivisionID, _Context);

            // Create the drop down list to be used on the screen.
            carddropdown = new List<CardDropDown>();
            carddropdown = loaddropdowns.ReturnDropDownList(CardList);
            return new JsonResult(CardList);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**EDIT----------------------------------------------------------------------**

So I changed the code as below and now I'm getting a parse error "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" I can't figure out what is going on as I can't see what the data is coming back that it can't parse. Is my code below not converting to JSON and if not, what am I missing?

```
    @section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Department').change(function () {
        var selectedDepartment = $("#Department").val();                 
        var cardSelect = $('#Card');
        cardSelect.empty();
        if (selectedDepartment != null && selectedDepartment != '') {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("/CheckOutCard?handler=CardsByDivisionAndStatus")', { divisionID: selectedDepartment }, function (cards) {
                if (cards != null && !jQuery.isEmptyObject(cards)) {
                    cardSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                        Card_ID: null,
                        Card_Number: ""

                    }))
                    $.each(cards, function (index, card) {
                        cardSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                            Card_ID: card.Card_ID,
                            Card_Number: card.Card_Number
                        }));

                    });

                };

            });                                
        }
    });
</script>
```

And here is my C# code for the procedure that I updated:

```
            // If the user selects a division then make sure to get the cards for that division only
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult OnGetCardsByDivisionAndStatus(string divisionID)
    {
        int checkinStatus;
        int intdivisionID;

        if (divisionID != "0" && divisionID != null)
        {
            // Retrieve a status of checked in so that only cards with a checked in status can
            // be checked out.
            checkinStatus = linqQuery.GetCardStatusByStatusDesc("Checked In", _Context);

            intdivisionID = Convert.ToInt32(divisionID);

            // Retrieve list of cards that have the checkin status ID
            CardList = linqQuery.GetCardListByStatusIDandDeptID(checkinStatus, intdivisionID, _Context);

            // Create the drop down list to be used on the screen.
            carddropdown = new List<CardDropDown>();
            carddropdown = loaddropdowns.ReturnDropDownList(CardList);
            var converted = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(carddropdown);
            return new JsonResult(converted);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what the problem was. Apparently I did not need to have the @URL.Action in my code. It was causing me to not hit my C# code which in return caused a null response back to my call. I have modified my javascript code to be as below to show what I am talking about. Thanks Mohsin for trying to help me out.

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Department').change(function ()
    {
        var selectedDepartment = $("#Department").val();
        var cardSelect = $('#Card');
        cardSelect.empty();
        if (selectedDepartment != null && selectedDepartment != '')
        {
            $.getJSON("/CheckOutCard?handler=CardsByDivisionAndStatus", { divisionID: selectedDepartment }, function (cards)
            {                                         
              $.each(cards, function (index, card)
              {
                  cardSelect.append($('<option/>',
                     {
                        value: card.card_ID,
                        text: card.card_Number
                     }));                        

               });

            });                                
        }
    });           
</script> }
```

Answer (score 3):

Rename your method to **OnGet**CardsByDivisionAndStatus (note "OnGet" prefix) and in jquery code change the url to

```
$.getJSON('/{PageRoute}?handler=CardsByDivisionAndStatus'
e.g.
$.getJSON('/About?handler=CardsByDivisionAndStatus'
```

Notice the handler querystring parameter name will be your method name without **OnGet** prefix.

Comment: Hi Mohsin, can you explain a little bit more about the name change? I want to make sure I understand the significance of it.

Comment: I believe the handler methods defined in Razor pages codebehind have to follow a convention "On{HttpMethod}" e.g OnGet or OnPost. 
Check the blog post https://codingblast.com/asp-net-core-razor-pages-handlers/

Comment: I appreciate that. You answer moved me forward a little but I'm still not sure how to return a JSON result from the C# side.

Comment: Not sure why you are serializing carddropdown and then passing it to jsonresult. JsonResult can input a List<T> and serialize it as json response e.g.

Try: return new JsonResult(carddropdown);